# Don't get to view in the Design View - NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I Declare two arrays and initialized them into the field declarations: the following is the example:

```
final String[] columnNames = {"First Name","Last Name","Sport","# of Years","Vegetarian"};
final Object[][] data = {
    {"Mary", "Campione","Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Alison", "Huml","Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Kathy", "Walrath","Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Sharon", "Zakhour","Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Philip", "Milne","Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};
```

and then drag and drop jTable in Frame. then go to the table Property>model>Custom Code, and there I write the following code:

```
    new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
```

When I run the application, working fine.But in this way, I don't get to view it in the Design View of Netbeans.

Update me! why Design view don't get to view it even I use the following code in the property to access the array

```
    new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently Netbeans not supporting this feature may be on later version it is available. It is only not showing view on design view but working fine. So, I think without design view you can continue your working, not problem at all.